# Does getting the same value for getting near a point in any direction in a multivariable function means the limit is that value too?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Consider the situation where we have:
$$ f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$$
and
$$ \vec{V} \in \mathbb{R}^n $$
and
$$ |\vec{V}| = 1 $$
and for each $\vec{V}$ we have:
$$ \lim_{t->0} f(t\vec{V}) = \vec{L} $$
Then can we say that $f$ has the $\lim$ of $\vec{L}$ in $\vec{0}$ ?

Comment: @DonThousand the claim is not true, take $$f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. As a counterexample take

$$f(x) = \frac{x_1x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^4}$$

where $f:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$. The claim is equivalent to taking the limit along any ray to the origin, which will be $0$ by squeeze theorem. However, along the path $x_1=x_2^2$:

$$\lim_{(x_2^2,x_2)\to(0,0)} = \frac{x_2^4}{x_2^4+x_2^4} = \frac{1}{2}$$

thus the limit does not exist.